# Ruby on rails - How to display different radio buttons once another radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I display different radio buttons once another radio button is checked in ruby on rails? For example if a user selects one category then I want to display the relevant subcategories but hide the other ones. I'd prefer a ruby on rails way instead of java script if there is one.

My form has something similar to this up until now:

```
<%= f.radio_button :category, "1", :checked => true %>
  <%= label :category_1, "1" %>

<%= f.radio_button :category, "2" %>
  <%= label :category_2, "2" %>
```

Comment: I don't think you will find a Ruby On Rails way... As it is a client side problem. Javascript is not scary :)

Comment: assign class to both of the button and write jquery/js for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be javascript unless you want to rerender the page, requiring a server roundtrip -- that not likely to be desirable performance/resource-wise.  But you really just need hidden divs for the subcategories to be made visible by javascript based on the onclick action for respective supercategory.  It's not a lot of javascript code.  (PS, if Oxynum converts his comment to an answer, pls give him the credit instead of me -- I only jumped in because I had to do exactly this recently).

Comment: Thanks for that. Ill wait for another day for Oxynum to answer, if he doesn't ill give you the credit.